# How do I retrieve search data from search form in express app?

Tags: javascript, rest, express, web

I am trying to get my first express app working and am stuck trying to get search query data to the server, here is my input form:

```
<form action="/search", method="POST" class="validated-form" novalidate>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" class="form-control rounded" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="search-addon"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">search</button>
    </div>
```

and here is the associated routing code:

```
router.post('/search', async (req,res, next) =>{
    console.log(req.body);
    });
```

I just get an empty {} back with no data. Can someone with express experience please help.

Comment: If it's `{}` you're using some kind of body parser middleware, just not the right one.

Comment: i don't think this the issue, I haven't passed an argument for middleware and the are the only thing i have in app.use in the index file app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

Comment: You should probably show more of your code. Also, are you directly posting the HTML form or are you using client-side JS to post it?